# Timeit timing a python function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to time the below function, however it shows me the error, can't import name val_in_range, what's the error, is there any other method to do it better?

```
import timeit

x = 10000000

def val_in_range(x, val):
    return val in range(x)

print (val_in_range(x,x/2))

timeit.timeit( 'val_in_range(x,x/2)', 'from __main__ import val_in_range, x',  number=10)
```

Output:

```
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 11, in <module>
  File "<timeit-src>", line 3, in inner
ImportError: cannot import name 'val_in_range'
```

Comment: I put that exact code in a source file (adding a shebang, `#!/usr/bin/env python3`) and ran it, and it ran fine. Is this your real code? I'm running Python 3.5 on Linux, for comparison.

Comment: try it here - https://repl.it/DTwI,

Comment: That link is either slow or broken for me, but regardless, I wouldn't try using online interpreters here; they may use strange mechanisms for executing the code (e.g. via `eval`/`exec`) that don't match standard Python behavior for either scripts or the normal interactive interpreter (e.g. the code may not be executed in the scope of `__main__`, or the values it defines not set there until the code completes, either of which would break your test case).

Comment: I am using it since I have python 2.7 installed and wanted it check timing for python 3, what option I have?

Comment: Timing it on local Python 2 and online Python 3 would be nigh useless anyway; the performance is only comparable on the same hardware. Why not install Py3 as well, so you can test with both locally? Side-note: If you want to see the speed benefits of Py3, change all cases of `x / 2` to `x // 2`; the former will produce a `float` on Py2 and break the `range` membership checking optimizations (which only apply to `int`), the latter produces `int` on both Py2 and Py3.

Comment: :) yes that's exactly for what I was checking the timings. And with lambda as mentioned by @maharshi things are working fine on online interpreter. They have both 2 and 3 so would compare there itself.

Comment: Flaw even then is that you have no idea what sort of resource sharing is occurring on an online interpreter. Unless you're literally the only person running on it, you could be getting 50% of a core one run, 12% the next, 97% the next, etc. If it's backed by a cloud, you could be dispatched to a Skylake CPU one time, and some decade old Pentium 4 chip the next. Local testing gets more reliable timings.

Comment: @garg10may If that's what you were after, why did you make it so complicated? Why not just `timeit.timeit('x/2 in range(x)', 'x = 10000000', number=10)`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann that's also a great suggestion, thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace
`timeit.timeit( 'val_in_range(x,x/2)', 'from __main__ import val_in_range, x',  number=10)`

with `timeit.timeit(lambda:val_in_range(x,x/2), number=10)`

you can print the value directly using the `print` statement.

Comment: this works, but what's wrong with my code, @ShadowRanger mentions that it works fine for him.

Comment: Your code will work on your local machine but not on online interpreters because of the way they handle files..